# formatting a double list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am having a trouble formatting my nav bar as I want. I have the html set up like this

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a><li>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
           </ul>
      <li><a href="#">2</a><li>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
           </ul>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">2.4</a></li>
           </ul>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

And my css is this

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #294076;
}

html {
background-image: url('2.jpeg');
}

nav {
min-width: 660px;
height:60px;
position absolute;
left:240px; 
}

header {
float: left;
min-width: 300px;
height: 60px;
font-size:45px;

}

nav ul {    
display: inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
margin: 6px -10px 0px 75px;
padding: 0;
font-size:25px;
}

nav ul > ul {
position: absolute;
}

ul > ul li {
float: top;
}

nav ul ul li {
display: none;
}

aside {
float: left;
font-size: 5px;
width: 160px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

section {
font-size: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 165px;
min-width: 800px;       
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul:hover ul li {
display: block;
font-size: 15px; 
}
```

The lists set with decimals don't fall directly inline under their parents lists. I have tried messing with the position attribute and giving it various spacing but it still does not appear to formart them correctly and moves them all on top of each other. I also am having trouble getting the two lists I have under 2 to appear side by side. They are just stacking on top of another. How can I get them to stand side by side and how do I get all of the decimal lists to format directly under their parent lists?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, a `ul` cannot be a child of another `ul`, it *must* be wrapped in an `li`. Similarly an `li` cannot be a child of another `li`. If you rewrite your HTML to properly enclose the `ul` elements within the relevant `li` elements you might find it works more reliably.

Comment: You guys are right, it behaves a lot better after I made the adjustments to <li><ul>'s. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the sub-menu `<ul>` elements in their proper `<li>` items. Like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2.4</a></li>
    </ul>
<li>
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/onugic/2/edit

Always provide a demo for HTML, CSS, JS related questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is not well-formed.  You have several `<li>` elements that are not closed.

Maybe this is closer to what you want?

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">1.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">1.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">2.1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">2.2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">2.3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">2.4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```